# Definition of (left) resolution

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $\mathsf C$ be an abelian category. A (left) resolution of an object $A$ is a nonnegative chain complex
$$\cdots \rightarrow P_2\rightarrow P_1\overset{\partial_1}\rightarrow P_0\rightarrow 0\rightarrow \cdots$$
quasi-isomorphic to the complex concentrated at $A$ in degree zero.

An equivalent definition often given is that the augmented complex
$$\cdots \rightarrow P_2\rightarrow P_1\rightarrow P_0\overset{\varepsilon}{\rightarrow} A\rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \cdots$$
is exact. Why are these definitions equivalent? It's easy to see that te augmented complex is indeed a chain complex (because quasi-isomorphisms are in particular chain maps).

> How do I show exactness properties involving $\varepsilon$?

Comment: Well, you haven't used the quasi-isomorphism condition...

Comment: I tried but haven't managed to.. The zeroth homology of $A[0]$ is $A$, and of the resolution is $P_0/ \operatorname{Ker}\partial$. How do I relate this to $\varepsilon$?

Comment: First, build a morphism between $P$ and $A[0]$ using $\epsilon$. Then show it is a quasi-isomorphism if and only if $P_1 \to P_0 \to A \to 0$ is exact.

Comment: @ZhenLin I understand this is what I need to do, but I don't see how.

Comment: @ZhenLin all I managed is to show $H_0(A[0])=A$ and $H_0(\text{resolution})=P_0/\ker \epsilon$. What now?

Comment: OK, and did you show that $H_n = 0$ for $n \ne 0$?

Comment: @ZhenLin yes, but I don't know how to show $A\cong P_0/\ker\epsilon$.

Comment: Well, did you use the hypothesis of exactness?

Comment: @ZhenLin all exactness gives me is $\ker\epsilon=\mathrm{im}\partial_1$ and that $\epsilon$ is an epi, but I don't see how to make any use of this..

Comment: Do you know the so-called first isomorphism theorem?

Comment: @ZhenLin ah, the thing I needed but failed to think about was the isomorphy of image and coimage in abelian categories. That settles this direction. How can I show exactness assuming $\varepsilon$ is a q.i though?

Comment: The proof works both ways, no?

Comment: @ZhenLin I don't see how. The first iso theorem gives an iso, but exactness is a statement about equality. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you are missing intuition. Did you try thinking concretely in terms of abelian groups?

Answer (score 0):

The claim is 
$$
\dotsb\rightarrow P_2\rightarrow P_1\xrightarrow d P_0\xrightarrow\varepsilon A\rightarrow 0\rightarrow\dotsb
$$
is exact if and only if the morphism of complexes $f:P_\bullet\to A[0]$ given by
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
\dotsb & \rightarrow & P_2 & \rightarrow & P_1 & \xrightarrow d & P_0 & \rightarrow & 0 & \rightarrow & \dotsb \\
& & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow\scriptsize\varepsilon & & \downarrow \\
\dotsb & \rightarrow & 0 & \rightarrow & 0 & \rightarrow & A & \rightarrow & 0 & \rightarrow & \dotsb
\end{array}
is a quasi-isomorphism.

The $(\Rightarrow)$ implication follows from 
$$
H^n(P_\bullet)\simeq H^n(A[0])\simeq 0
$$ 
for $n\neq 0$ and $H^0(f):P_0/\ker\varepsilon\to A$ is the map $x+\ker\varepsilon\mapsto x$, which is an isomorphism by the isomorphism theorems.

Can you prove the $(\Leftarrow)$ implication?

Comment: Sorry, how do you know the arrow $H_0(f)$ looks like that? Also, I'm working in an abelian category without elements. Thanks!